# want to change the logging format

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

Now I'm implementing logging mechanism in my project. I can see the log details in cmd. The problem is, the log comes like

```
0 [main] INFO dca.bca.cur.client.actions.CreateGroup  - Inside the create group    
318 [main] ERROR dca.bca.cur.client.actions.CreateGroup  - Group Deployment failed
```

I don't want the class name in this log. Just want to see the message.
Like this format

```
[INFO] [02:42:21.786] Inside the create group.
[INFO] [02:42:21.786] Group Deployment failed
```

Comment: What does your `log4j.properties` look like`

Comment: You'll need to change your message pattern. As Lutz sais: Show us what you got.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your conversion patter to the one bellow in your log4j.xml

```
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p [%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %m%n" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the pattern in `Log4j properties` file.

A sample layout would look like this

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />
</layout>
```

[Refer this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_patternlayout.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In either the `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` configuration file, you need to set the conversion pattern to:

```
[%p] [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %m%n
```

See the [`PatternLayout`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) documentation on how you can build different formats or customise this one further. The time can be specified using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns.